# run different scripts in content_scripts based on "matches"

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm just getting started with JavaScript and am trying to modify the script in the MDN tutorial, [Your First WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension)

I'm trying to draw a red or blue box around a web page depending on whether it's http:// or https://. However, only one script will run.

The manifest.json is this:

```js
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "HTTPS Detect",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Draws a blue border around HTTPS protected websites. Non-HTTPS sites are given a red border, indicating they do not provide encryption.",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
 
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "js": ["httpsdetect.js"],
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["nohttps.js"]
      
 }
   
 ]
  
 }
```

The httpsdetect.js is as follows:

```js
document.body.style.border = "5px solid blue";
```

And nohttps.js is:

```js
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [content_scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts) key is an array of Objects (each containing a mandatory `matches` key), not just a single Object with multiple copies of the same keys. The way you have it, you have two `matches` and two `js` keys within the same Object. This gets interpreted as the key later in the file overriding the prior one(s).

For each `matches` it should be a different Object in the array.  Your *manifest.json* could look like:

*manifest.json*:

```json
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "HTTPS Detect",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Draws a blue border around HTTPS protected websites. Non-HTTPS sites are given a red border, indicating they do not provide encryption.",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "js": ["httpsdetect.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["nohttps.js"]
    }
   ]
 }
```

Alternately, given that you are loading only one file, you could load the same JavaScript file into both `http` and `https` pages and change what you are doing based on the URL matching `http` or `https`.  If it was the case that some code was shared between the two scripts, doing so might be more efficient (or you could have the shared code in a file that is loaded into both while loading a separate file with the non-shared code into each). In which case, you could use either a single [match pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/match_patterns) that matches both, or multiple match patterns within the `matches` array.